# Using Turtle Beach XO Four Stealth Headset with Macbook Pro Retina 15", Mid-2012

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones, microphone

I've read a few older posts about headsets and the TRRS headphone/mic input [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/55870/125556), [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/51374/125556), [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/6394/125556), [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/90344/macbook-pro-mid-2012-microphone-input) and the consensus seems to be that the Macbook is expecting "line-level" input (either that or you have the mysterious occasional answer of "mine works!").

My question is more clearly related to this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/99414/125556): which is, *if these Macbook Pros only accept a powered/line-level input, then how do they recognize the iPhone earbuds/microphone?* I have not seen this addressed anywhere else.

My Turtle Beach XO Four Stealth is not powered, its only hookup is a TRRS jack. When I plug it in the Input doesn't switch from internal to external as it does for my Apple earbuds/mic.

Any explanations for the difference in behavior? I assume this may just be dependent on the hardware of the headset, but what would this difference be.

[image: Turtle Beach TRRS vs. Apple iPhone Earbud TRRS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple use the CTIA standard TRRS while most other companies use the OMTP standard.

These 2 pictures should short it out. Notice the Ground and microphones are switched.

- [OMTP](http://www.sunnycomputer.com.au/ebay/Cable/AuxSplitter/pic4_IBM.JPG)
- [CTIA](http://www.sunnycomputer.com.au/ebay/Cable/AuxSplitter/pic4_iPhone.JPG)

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Sort. Sort it out. Short means something else and would be a bad thing in this context.